# Cannot generate post request for multiple data

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am trying to take input multiple data object in post request, but getting such error.

```
non_field_errors: [ Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got a list.     ]
```

**models.py**

```
class OrderProduct(BaseModel):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_product_price = models.FloatField(blank=False,null=False,default=0)  # product may belong to offer do the price
    order_product_qty = models.FloatField(default=1)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class OrderProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

     def update(self,instance,validated_data):
        product = self.validated_data.pop('product')
        order = self.validated_data.pop('order')

        instance.orderproduct_qty = 
        self.validated_data.get('orderproduct_qty',instance.orderproduct_qty)
        instance.product = product
        instance.order = order
        instance.save()
        return instance

     class Meta:
        model = OrderProduct
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    if request.data['contact_number'] == '':
        request.POST._mutable =True
        request.data['contact_number'] = request.user.mobile_number
        request.POST._mutable = False
    serializer = OrderSerializer(data=request.data,many=isinstance(request.data,list),context={'request': request})
    print(serializer)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(user = request.user,created_by = request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**urls.py**

```
path('orderproduct/',views.OrderProductList.as_view()),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `serializer.save()`. It's only perform `create()` action which is only create one and accept dictionary data type only. If you want to save multiple data like that, you will have to override the `create` function of the serializer class. You can do something similar like this or run a for loop.

**serializers.py**

```py
    def create(self, validate_data):
       # Get the data objects you need to perform bulk create
       order_products = OrderProduct.objects.bulk_create(validate_data)
       return order_products
```

**views.py**

```py
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
       # Replace the serializer.save() by this line to trigger the create method in serializer
       self.perform_create(serializer)
       return Response(...)
```

Comment: Thanks Quang Võ . bulk_create only works if there don't have any related data field.So, i used a for loop in views.py. Now its working. :)